# Operation over the reals with multiplication to form a field

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

So the set {$\Re\backslash\{0\},\times,\wedge$}, where $\times$ is multiplication and $\wedge$ is exponentiation, is not a field because for instance exponentiation is not commutative ($a\wedge b$ does not in general equal $b\wedge a$) among other things.

Is there an operation $\circ$ that does follow the field axioms along with $\times$? There can't be one over $\Re$ because {$\Re, \times$} is not an abelian group so it will need to be over $\Re\backslash\{0\}$ or some smaller set, and $\circ$ has to be distributable over $\times$ as well as follow the other commutative group axioms except there only needs to be an inverse with respect to the $\circ$ operation for the set $\Re\backslash\{0,1\}$ because $1$ is the multiplicative identity.

If one does exist, what can we say about the properties of the structure $\{\Re,+,\times,\circ\}$? Also, more generally, does a field exist for each repetition of this pattern, for example a field of the form $\{\Re\backslash\{0,1\},\circ,\odot\}$, where $\circ$ is the same as above and $\odot$ follows the field axioms with $\circ$ as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the multiplication on the non-zero reals cannot be the addition in a field, since it has both torsion and non-torsion elements.

More precisely, you have $(-1)^2 = 1$ which translates to $2x = 0$ for some non-zero $x$ when written additively, but then $2$ is not invertible in the field and thus the characteristic is $2$ which would imply that $2y = 0$ for all $y$ which would translate back to $z^2 = 1$ for all $z$ which is clearly not true.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a ring, but not a field.

As an abelian group, $(\mathbb{R}, \cdot )$ is isomorphic to the (additive) group $\mathbb{R} \times (\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z})$; the isomorphism is given by taking logarithms and signs.

There is an obvious way to put a ring structure on this group: you make it into the ring $\mathbb{R} \times (\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z})$.

However, it is impossible to put any ring structure on this abelian group that makes it into a field, because:

- It has a nonzero element satisfying $2 \cdot a = 0$ (and thus $2 = 0$)
- It has an element satisfying $2 \cdot a \neq 0$ (and thus $2 \neq 0$)

(by $2$, I mean the element $1+1$, where $1$ is the multiplicative unit)

Comment: But the OP asked about the field axioms.

Comment: I just realized the OP also mentioned "or some smaller set" which is of course doable with the idea from this answer, though it does not give any new structure, as one just gets the reals back.